# am trying to automate tests on nopcommerce website as a practice but after first and second step it stops

Tags: selenium-webdriver, testing, automated-tests, cucumber, testng

> am trying to automate tests on https://demo.nopcommerce.com/ website as a practice but after first and second step it stops and says test passed without continuing to the next steps am using selenium and cucumber and testng
> am automating it on edge driver

```
Reigster.feature file
Feature: user register new account successfully.

  Scenario: user register with valid data
Given user open browser
Given user navigate to register page
When user select gender "female"
And user enter firstname "Mohamed" and lastname "Sabry"
And user enter valid email "sabry@gmail.com"
And user fills password "123456" field and confirm it
And user click on register button
Then success message is displayed
Then user close browser
```

RegisterPage.java
```package pages;

````
import org.openqa.selenium.By;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.testng.asserts.SoftAssert;

public class RegisterPage {

WebDriver driver;

SoftAssert soft=new SoftAssert();

public RegisterPage(WebDriver driver){
    this.driver=driver;
    PageFactory.initElements(driver,this);
}

public WebElement navigateToRegister(){


    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/div[1]/ul/li[1]/a"));
}

public WebElement genderMale(){

    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gender-male\"]"));
}
public WebElement genderFemale(){

    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"gender-female\"]"));
}

public WebElement firstName(){


    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"FirstName\"]"));
}

public WebElement lastName(){
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"LastName\"]"));
}

public WebElement email(){
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Email\"]"));
}

public WebElement password(){
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"Password\"]"));
}

public WebElement confirmPassword(){
    return driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"ConfirmPassword\"]"));
}

    public void registerButton(){
        driver.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id=\"register-button\"]")).click();
    }

    public void result(){
        String expectedResult="//*[@id=\"register-button\"]";
        String actualResult=driver.findElement(By.xpath("/html/body/div[6]/div[3]/div/div/div/div[2]/div[1]")).getText();
        soft.assertEquals(actualResult,expectedResult);

    }

}```
````

(RegisterStepDef.java)

````
```package stepDefenations;

import io.cucumber.java.en.And;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Given;
import io.cucumber.java.en.Then;
import io.cucumber.java.en.When;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.edge.EdgeDriver;

import pages.RegisterPage;

public class RegisterStepDef {

WebDriver driver=null;
RegisterPage register;

@Given("user open browser")
public void user_open_browser() throws InterruptedException {
    String edgeDriverPath="C:\\Users\\engmo\\IdeaProjects\\AutomationProject\\drivers\\msedgedriver.exe";
    System.setProperty("webdriver.edge.driver",edgeDriverPath);
    driver=new EdgeDriver();
    driver.navigate().to("https://demo.nopcommerce.com/");
    driver.manage().window().maximize();
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    register=new RegisterPage(driver);
}

@When("user navigate to register page")
public void user_navigate_to_register_page() throws InterruptedException {

    register.navigateToRegister().click();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

@And("user select gender {string}")
public void user_select_gender(String gender) throws InterruptedException {
    if(gender.equals("male")) {
        register.genderMale().click();
    } else {
        register.genderFemale().click();
    }
    Thread.sleep(1000);

}

@And("user enter firstname {string} and lastname {string}")
public void user_enter_firstname_and_lastname(String first_name, String last_name)  {
    register.firstName().sendKeys(first_name);
    register.lastName().sendKeys(last_name);

}

@And("user enter valid email {string}")
public void user_enter_valid_email(String email) throws InterruptedException {
    register.email().sendKeys(email);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

@And("user fills password {string} field and confirm it")
public void user_fills_password_field_and_confirm_it(String password) throws InterruptedException {
    register.password().sendKeys(password);
    register.confirmPassword().sendKeys(password);
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

@And("user click on register button")
public void user_click_on_register_button() throws InterruptedException {
    register.registerButton();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

@And("success message is displayed")
public void success_message_is_displayed() throws InterruptedException {
    register.result();
    Thread.sleep(1000);
}

@Then("user close browser")
public void user_close_browser() throws InterruptedException {
    Thread.sleep(3000);
    driver.quit();
}
}```
````

i don't know why it stops after selecting gender and says passed
it opens the browser and then navigates to register page
then it selects the gender
and the test stops saying it is passed without completing the steps

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you have an issue, because annotations in code and Gherkin spec are different.

```js
Given user navigate to register page
When user select gender "female"
```

When in your code you are using `When` and `And`

```js
@When("user navigate to register page")
public void user_navigate_to_register_page() throws InterruptedException { ... }

@And("user select gender {string}")
public void user_select_gender(String gender) throws InterruptedException { ... }
```

Conditions from Gherkin spec and Definitions class should match.

Comment: Nice observation +1